# Exporting embedded Adobe PDF Reader text

Tags: pdf, text, components, pdf-parsing

I have an embedded Adobe PDF Reader in my Windows application. When I open a certain PDF file I need to do is manually select a text in that PDF and transfer it over to a textbox. I haven't done much work with PDF embedded components. But I can see two potential solutions. Either to find where in embedded component selected text can be grabbed from or use a Clipboard to cut selected text and transfer it over to a textbox.

Can anyone help me with this? So to put it plainly I want to know how the best way to access text (selected or not) in embedded PDF Reader Component.

Comment: I'd recommend some searching around ".net PDF parsing" or ".net PDF component" - they might get you some ideas to try.